# Python Function running on a random date

Tags: python, date, random, time

```
#first and last day of every month

s_january, e_january =      ("1/1/2017"), ("1/31/2017")  
s_february, e_february =    ("2/1/2017"), ("2/28/2017")
s_march, e_march =          ("3/1/2017"), ("3/31/2017")
s_april, e_april =          ("4/1/2017"), ("4/30/2017")
s_may, e_may =              ("5/1/2017"), ("5/31/2017")
s_june, e_june =            ("6/1/2017"), ("6/30/2017")
s_july, e_july =            ("7/1/2017"), ("7/31/2017")
s_august, e_august =        ("8/1/2017"), ("8/31/2017")
s_September, e_September =  ("9/1/2017"), ("9/30/2017")
s_october, e_october =      ("10/1/2017"), ("10/31/2017")
s_november, e_november =    ("11/1/2017"), ("11/30/2017")
s_december, e_december =    ("12/1/2017"), ("12/31/2017")

def foo(s_date, e_date):
    does stuff


foo(s_january, e_january)
foo(s_february, e_february)
foo(s_march, e_march)
foo(s_april, e_april)
foo(s_may, e_may)
foo(s_june, e_june)
foo(s_july, e_july)
foo(s_august, e_august)
foo(s_september, e_september)
foo(s_october, e_october)
foo(s_november, e_november)
foo(s_december, e_december)
```

I have a function that on a random date does stuff, but I have to call the function for every month, if I put the range for year I don't get the result that I want.

Is there any better way to avoid running it 12 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your dates in a dictionary rather than 24 variables, and make life easier for yourself by computing the first and last day of each month. It would be useful also to represent your dates as `datetimes` not strings, since it's clear from your question header that you want to do computation on them.

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

year = 2017
dates = {}
for month in range(1,13):
    dates[(year,month)] = (
        datetime.date(year,month,1),
        datetime.date(year,month,1)
              + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
              - relativedelta.relativedelta(days=1))
```

The first element in each tuple is computed straightforwardly as the first day of the month. The second date is the same date, but with one month added (first day of the next month) and then one day subtracted, to get the last day of the month.

Then you can do:

```
for (year,month),(start,end) in dates.items():
    print(year, month, foo (start,end))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to keep all start end end dates:

```
import calendar
import datetime as dt


def foo(s_date, e_date):
    print ("Doing something between {} and {}".format(s_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), e_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))


def getMonths(year):
    result = {}
    for month in range(1, 13):
        lastDayOfMonth = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        result[month] = (dt.datetime(year, month, 1), dt.datetime(year, month, lastDayOfMonth))
    return result


for month, start_end_dates in getMonths(2018).items():
    foo(*start_end_dates)
```

Prints:

```
Doing something between 01/01/2018 and 31/01/2018
Doing something between 01/02/2018 and 28/02/2018
Doing something between 01/03/2018 and 31/03/2018
...
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by putting the range for year?

You could consider putting your dates to a dictionary or nested lists.